# Update no avanza - db file sequential read

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, plsql, oracle-11g

Necesitaría obtener su ayuda sobre el siguiente update:

> ```
> UPDATE IDP_USERS_RELATED_DATA_TEMP IRDT SET ISUPDATED = 1, DIGITALUSERID =
>                  ( SELECT IRD.DIGITALUSERID FROM IDP_RELATED_DATA IRD 
>                    WHERE IRD.KEY = 'IDCONTACTO' 
>                          AND IRDT.ID_CONTACT = IRD.VALUE
>                          AND IRDT.ID_CONTACT NOT IN (
> SELECT ID_CONTACT 
>                  FROM (
>                  SELECT IRDT.ID_CONTACT, IRD.DIGITALUSERID
>                  FROM IDP_USERS_RELATED_DATA_TEMP IRDT, IDP_RELATED_DATA IRD
>                  WHERE
>                     KEY = 'IDCONTACTO'
>                    AND VALUE = ID_CONTACT ) X
>                  GROUP BY ID_CONTACT
>                  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DIGITALUSERID) > 1
>                          ) AND IRDT.DIGITALUSERID IS NULL
>                 )
>                 WHERE USERNAME IN (select username 
>                 from ( select username, rownum as rnum from IDP_USERS_RELATED_DATA_TEMP 
>                 WHERE 
>                 ID_CONTACT NOT IN (
> SELECT ID_CONTACT 
>                  FROM (
>                  SELECT IRDT.ID_CONTACT, IRD.DIGITALUSERID
>                  FROM IDP_USERS_RELATED_DATA_TEMP IRDT, IDP_RELATED_DATA IRD
>                  WHERE
>                     KEY = 'IDCONTACTO'
>                    AND VALUE = ID_CONTACT ) X
>                  GROUP BY ID_CONTACT
>                  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DIGITALUSERID) > 1
>                         ) AND ISUPDATED = 0 
>                 ) x 
>                 );
> ```

No logro que finalice. Y El evento de espera que veo es:

```
Event                      SEGMENT_TYPE   SEGMENT_NAME                 FILE_ID   BLOCK_ID  BLOCKS
-------------------------- -------------- --------------------------- -------- ---------- -------
db file sequential read    INDEX          IDP_RELATED_DATA_KEY_VALUE        34     381456      16
```

Nunca avanza de ese punto.

Version:

```
  Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 - RAC ASM 
Linux 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1
```

Datos de las tablas:

```
TABLE_NAME                           NUM_ROWS
------------------------------       ----------
IDP_USERS_RELATED_DATA_TEMP          72412
IDP_RELATED_DATA                     51137205
```

Datos Indices:

```
    INDEX_NAME                     INDEX_TYPE   TABLE_NAME                   
------------------------------ ------------ -----------------------------
IDP_RELATED_DATA_PK            NORMAL       IDP_RELATED_DATA             
IDP_RELATED_DATA_DIGITALUSERID NORMAL       IDP_RELATED_DATA             
IDP_RELATED_DATA_KEY_VALUE     NORMAL       IDP_RELATED_DATA             
ID_CONTACT                     NORMAL       IDP_USERS_RELATED_DATA_TEMP
```

Intenté con algún HINT, sin resultados:

```
> WHERE USERNAME IN (select /*+ rule */ username
```

He recreado los indices sin resultados.
Corrí estadisticas en todo el esquema.
El Advisor sugirió un cambio en el plan de ejecución, que no mejoró nada.

Podrán sugerirme como optimizar la sentencia?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: lo que veo es que estas consultando reiteradamente la tabla que quieres actualizar y eso causaría bloqueos, ya intentaste guardar en una tabla tempral tu "Select" para que el update solo haga join a esa tabla temporal?,
con eso podrías evitar bloqueos.

Comment: En las sub-consultas haces dos productos cartesianos (o es lo que parece) entre las tablas. Cada producto cartesiano entre la tabla con 72 mil registros con la tabla con 51 millones de registros produce 3 billones 702 mil 947 millones de registros. 
Y luego, uno de estos productos se realiza una vez por cada fila que se vaya a actualizar. Esto va a tardar _eternamente_. Si no son productos cartesianos, podrías mejorar la legibilidad usando la sintaxis `inner join` (que está disponible desde hace muuuuchos años) o por lo menos calificar las columnas en el where.

Comment: gracias a ambos...estamos trabajando en las recomendaciones.